# Number of haters a person can have

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

There are n people in a party. Each person is numbered from 0 - n-1. Every person may have a hater or not. A person X hates person Y if any of the condition is true:-

- X is a direct hater of Y
- Z hates Y and X hates Z so X indirectly hates Y

Each person can have only 1 direct hater and no 2 person will hate each other.
Given an array `Arr` where the Arr[i] is direct hater of person i. -1 denotes the person has no direct hater.
Find the number of groups such that no one has a direct or indirect hater in the group.

Examples:

- [-1, 0 , 1] - output 3 - Groups {0}, {1}, {2}
- [1, -1, 3, -1] - output 2 - Groups {0, 2}, {1, 3}

This problem seems to be connected with finding number of connected components but I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: "Z hates Y and X and Z..." So Z hates Z? And if Z hates Y and X, why would that make X indirectly hate Y? Regardless, given those rules, you should be able to build a directed graph easily enough, with connections between nodes to represent the hatreds.

Comment: no one can hate themselves so no cycles and one person has only 1 direct hater.

Comment: Yes, I understood that part, which is why I questioned your second bullet point, because it says that Z hates Z. Perhaps you need to change the wording there? And there *can* be cycles. If Z hates Y and Y directly hates X, and X directly hates Z, that doesn't violate the rules. Unless an indirect hatred is the same as a direct hatred. If that's the case, you need to more clearly specify your rules.

Comment: A can be hated by at most 1, but A himself hate more than 1,right?

Comment: @JimMischel Sorry that was a typo fixed it. Indirect hate cannot go beyond 1 step. X hates Y, Y hates Z and Z hates A doesn't mean X hates A

Comment: It would be useful if you would show an example that includes indirect hatred. Also, if the output from the first example includes the individual nodes, shouldn't the output from the second example also include the individual nodes? If not, why?

Comment: As for your previous comment, please consider: X hates Y *directly*. Y hates Z *directly*. So Z *indirectly* hates X, right? Or for that matter, what prevents Z from *directly* hating X. Either way, you have a cycle. Furthermore, X *indirectly* hates Z. I maintain that the rules are not sufficiently specified.

Comment: if we don't make a distinction between direct/indirect hate, can it be finding number of `maximal independent set' problem?